# How to Upload Data from SQL to AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

I have a SQL database running on some server. I would like to upload this to AWS Cloud Search. Is there a direct way to accomplish this, or do I need to run some manual process, such as running scripts to (or manually doing this):

1. Convert db table to CSV.
2. Upload CSV to AWS cloud search.
3. Repeat any time data changes.

This just seems really convoluted. Is there something I am missing, can AWS be configured to pull directly from SQL?